# How to Z-Index(Z-Sorting) windows 8 UIElements in 3D Perspective?

Tags: c#, windows-8, z-index, transform, uielement

In general you can apply 3-D effects(x,y,z,rotationX,rotationY,rotationZ...) to any `UIElement` using the so called "Perspective Transforms":

```
<Image x:Name="img1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Width="200" Source="img1.jpg">
        <Image.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationY="3" RotationX="40"/>
        </Image.Projection>
</Image>
```

but with no Z-Index(Z-Sorting)!
when UIElements overlapped they don't render properly in perspective.

in AS3 I use this function to zsort objects :

```
public function zSort():void
    {
        var i:uint;
        var zList:Array = [];
        for (i=0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
        {
            var mtx:Matrix3D = this.getChildAt(i).transform.getRelativeMatrix3D(this.parent);
            zList.push( { sp:this.getChildAt(i), z:mtx.position.z } );
        }
        zList.sortOn("z", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
        for (i=0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
        {
            this.setChildIndex(zList[i].sp, i);
        }
    }
```

Is there similar solutions in c#? or things work deferent in windows 8?

I found this Silverlight tutorial ["Using projection to build a 3D carousel in Silverlight 3"](http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/06/12/using-projection-to-build-a-3d-carousel-in-silverlight-3/)
images seems to be zindex automatically witch is not what happen in WINRT?

Answer (score 0):

If you place your `Image` in a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209267.aspx), you will be able to set the [zIndex dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindexproperty.aspx).

Comment: But how to zindex them in perspective? like images in 3D carousel or in a rotating  cube?